# .NET Core - Is there a way to set an enum to have a default value when using a Select Tag Helpler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

So I'm converting an enum to a dropdown list via the .NET Core tag helper.  It's pretty standard.

**Enum**

```
public enum DistanceType
{
    [Display(Name = "1 Mile")]
    [Description("1")]
    OneMile = 1,

    [Display(Name = "5 Miles")]
    [Description("5")]
    FiveMiles = 2,

    [Display(Name = "10 Miles")]
    [Description("10")]
    TenMiles = 3,

    [Display(Name = "20 Miles")]
    [Description("20")]
    TwentyMiles = 4
}
```

**View**

```
<select asp-for="EnumDistanceType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DistanceType>()">
</select>
```

So what I want to do is every time I render this enum into a dropdown list I want it to select, by default, a value other than the first one.  So for example, every time I render the dropdown it displays "5 Miles" to the user instead of "1 Mile".  I don't want to change the order of the enum though, I want the dropdown to be on the second object.

Is there some easy way to do this by just using a tag on the enum?  Or if not in the enum is there some way to do this in the tag helper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set value for `EnumDistanceType` property for your model instance.

Let's say your model class is

```
public class DistanceViewModel
{
    public DistanceType EnumDistanceType { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller action may be:

```
public IActionResult DistanceOption(int id)
{
    var model = new DistanceViewModel();
    model.EnumDistanceType = DistanceType.FiveMiles;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do it via a tag on the enum itself.  This dropdown is pretty much on every page of my site and I'd rather not set it on every page.  I guess I could have the constructor of the ViewModel set it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEnumSelectListWithDefaultValue<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, TEnum defaultValue) 
            where TEnum : struct
        {
            var selectList = htmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList<TEnum>().ToList();
            selectList.Single(x => x.Value == $"{(int)(object)defaultValue}").Selected = true;
            return selectList;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
<select asp-for="EnumProperty" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectListWithDefaultValue<SomeEnum>(defaultValue: SomeEnum.SomeEnumValue)">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Have a look :)

```
<select asp-for="EnumDistanceType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DistanceType>()">
    <option selected value="2">FiveMiles</option>
</select>
```